# Arch Linux from live USB - how do I launch the GUI?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, x-windows, liveusb

I run Arch from a live USB. I want to use it to repair a broken Windows XP installation. I was presented with a console and I thought that starting the GUI windows system would be as simple as issuing `startx`. I was wrong. So how do I launch a GUI windows environment from the live USB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arch linux is extremely simple OS. It is made for people who want to build a system for themselves, i.e. it does not come with packages that you don't need. That means, you have to install by yourself almost everything you need, including window system.

Since xorg is not installed, you cannot just do `startx`.

First, you have to install xorg. 
Secondly, you have to decide what DE you want to use and install it.
Third, you have to configure `.xinitrc` to run DE when you type `startx`.
Don't forget about video drivers.

I strongly suggest to follow [beginners guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_Guide) or if you are experienced in linux, [installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide) to understand how to configure you Arch Linux.

Also, if you are not a linux enthusiast and you want to just repair you windows(I am not sure how are you going to repair your windows with it), you should pick an OS that comes with GUI and a complete DE, so you won't spend hours to just configure and then delete it from flash drive.

Take a look at: [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/), [puppy linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm), and I just found [Slitaz](http://www.slitaz.org/en/).

Comment: Thanks - I will accept your answer if you add some info on how to install (for instance) gnome from the command line (and I am sure you will get some votes overtime) - just the commands will do - a shame that from a live usb one has to do this every time. I understand arch is as simple as can be but I would expect the live cd to have at least xorg - and some minimal windows system - duh

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Arch linux would use its point if it had a DE installed. [The philosophy](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/The_Arch_Way) that they (and me too) follow is simplicity and freedom. Users wouldn't have  complete freedom if their OS comes with, for example, `xorg` installed, because not everybody wants GUI or xorg

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I am sorry, I won't write instructions on how to configure arch linux since Arch people already did [that](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide). At the [end](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Graphical_User_Interface) of the guid, it explains how to install GUI